# Neo4jClient Transactions - Auth Error on Transaction Completion

Tags: transactions, neo4jclient

I am attempting to use the latest pre-release of Neo4jClient transaction support (Neo4jClient 1.1.0-Tx00008).  I have tried the most simple example, but seem to always get an authentication error whenever the transaction completes (Neo4j Community 2.2.2 or 2.3).  The following code:

```
        var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://user:password@localhost:7474/db/data"));
        graphClient.Connect();

        using (var transaction = graphClient.BeginTransaction())
        {
            graphClient.Cypher.Create("(n:TestNode {Name:'TestNode2'})").ExecuteWithoutResults(); 
            graphClient.Cypher.Create("(n:TestNode {Name:'TestNode3'})").ExecuteWithoutResults(); 
            transaction.Commit();     
        }
```

Always results in this error when the transaction commit is called, or if I exclude the `transaction.Commit()` and allow the scope to end:

```
Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.

The response status was: 401 Unauthorized

The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: <html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Without using any transaction scope, the nodes are created fine. I have looked through the unit tests in the source code, but do not see any difference in how to call this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use an AuthWrapper for the moment I'm afraid which will look like:

```
private class HttpClientAuthWrapper : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly AuthenticationHeaderValue _authenticationHeader;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HttpClientAuthWrapper(string username, string password)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            return;

        var encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password));
        _authenticationHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(encoded));
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if(_authenticationHeader != null)
            request.Headers.Authorization = _authenticationHeader;
        return _client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Which is then used like so:

```
var client = new GraphClient(
    new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"), 
    new HttpClientAuthWrapper("user", "pass#")
    );
client.Connect();
```

This will get all the transactions to use the correct authentication header. Thank you for raising it on Github as well - we can look into getting it properly solved!

(by the by - the code is all from: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2015/03/27/upgrading-your-neo4j-from-xxx-to-2.2.0ndashhaving-authorization-trouble.aspx)